# Ros install 10.6.8 make -j8 problem undefined symbols

Tags: macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still trying to run the command:

```
make -j8
```

on Mac OS-X SnowLeopard (10.6.8)

When i do I get this problem

```
Macbook:build **********$ make -j8
    ...
        [ 61%] Built target turtle_teleop_key
        [ 61%] Built target mimic
        [ 61%] Built target relay
        [ 61%] [ 61%] [ 61%] Built target throttle
        Built target rosbag
        Built target switch_mux
        [ 61%] Built target turtlesim_node
        [ 61%] Built target play
        [ 61%] Built target record
        Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/librxtools.dylib
        ld: warning: in /System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
        ld: warning: in /usr/lib/libwx_macud-2.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
        ld: warning: duplicate dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib
        ld: warning: duplicate dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib
        ld: warning: duplicate dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
        Undefined symbols:
          "wxGetTopLevelParent(wxWindow*)", referenced from:
              wxTopLevelWindowBase::IsActive()      in topic_display_generated.cpp.o
              wxTopLevelWindowBase::IsActive()      in topic_display_dialog.cpp.o
              wxTopLevelWindowBase::IsActive()      in rosout_generated.cpp.o
              wxTopLevelWindowBase::IsActive()      in rosout_setup_dialog.cpp.o
          "vtable for wxwxColumnListNode", referenced from:
              wxwxColumnListNode::wxwxColumnListNode(wxListBase*, wxwxColumnListNode*, wxwxColumnListNode*, wxListItem*, wxListKey const&)in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/librxtools.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anybody have any idea of what to do to fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44545/ros-install-10.6.8-make--j8-problem-undefined-symbols/) by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You get a warning from the linker:

```
ld: warning: in /usr/lib/libwx_macud-2.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
```

Which means that you are building 64-bit, but that library is not built for 64-bit.  If that is the case it might contain the undefined symbols which appear later in the error message.

How did you install wxPython?  The recommended method is using a binary from wxPython's website.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on 2012-09-27**:
Yes that is how i installed it.
I looked into the wxPython again and found I'd installed the 32bit version only because I had Python 2.6. I've now installed Python 2.7 and a new wxPython however when I run CMake it says:
Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-09-27**:
You'll need to install empy (sudo pip install empy)

**Comment by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on 2012-09-28**:
It was complaining about empy because it was installed in the Python2.6 folder instead of the python 2.7.

I've fixed that and I'm still getting the same problem. I also reinstalled wxPython from the link in the wiki page. Any other suggestions?